# Printing out value of array of numbers-Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

Alright so I have this code

```
SortScore PROC
call clrscr

 mov ecx, LENGTHOF studentsAverage
 dec ecx

L1: push ecx                                                                
mov esi, OFFSET studentsAverage             
L2: mov eax,[esi]                               
cmp [esi+4],eax                             
jge L3                                      ;jump to L3 if greater 

xchg eax,[esi+4]                            ;exchange values
mov [esi],eax                               ;

L3: add esi,4                                   ;move to next value 
loop L2                                     ;go back to L2
pop ecx                                     ;bring back the ecx
loop L1                                     ;go back to L1

L4: ret
```

I'm pretty sure it works, I just need to know how to modify it to display the values.

Comment: This is a bubble sort. Do you want to print out the array you have sorted?

Comment: We aren't here to solve your tasks for you.  Take a shot at solving it and then ask here for help if you get stuck trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to convert from a number to ASCII ? I've replied that in another answer :

[Converting an ascii character into decimal in Assembly for use with WriteConsoleA and readConsoleA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785692/converting-an-ascii-character-into-decimal-in-assembly-for-use-with-writeconsolea/5785786#5785786)